# Detect unresponsive service process

Tags: c#, service, process, windows-services, windows-server

I have a service daemon (running in Windows Server) that runs 24/7 (or it should) that I didn't write or have access to the source code.

For some unknown reason the service sometimes stops responding (my guess is that it deadlocks). This is a mail service so I know it has stopped working when I don't receive any mails from it in 'n' time (n is never fixed).

Currently the only programmatical way I can check if it's non-responsive is trying to stop the service, and if that times-out, I know it's dead/zombie. I can then force-kill the service process and just run the service again.

I want to automate this process (i.e., code a "watchdog"), and would like to periodically check if the service has stopped responding without trying to stop it first (I don't want to stop the service if it's really working).

Is there any programmatical way to check if a process is not responding which is not trying to stop it?

I don't have any clue how the service works internally so I can't just send a signal to it and wait for response (since I don't know what signals it would respond to, other than attempting to cleanly stop it).

This has been on and off in my head for some time and I haven't been able to find an answer.

If there's nothing else, I'd just make it stop every night or so (that'd be acceptable even if it's working), but if there's any way, I'd prefer to have some daemon check it every 10 minutes or so (stopping and restarting the service every 10 minutes would NOT be acceptable if it's working).

I'd appreciate any hints on where to look, if there's any.

PS: the code for service stopping, process killing or service starting is not a problem and I'm not looking for that... I'd only like a hint or direction on how to check if it has became non-responsive without knowing how it is programmed.

Comment: Try querying the service status; if the service doesn't respond to stop requests, it might not be responding to query requests either.

Comment: I dont think you can do do this if you dont have any access to the program. Well there could be some ways to do it but they would all take a really long time to implement i think. Like find out what ram addresses the program writes to on runtime correctly and what it does difrently when its deadlocked. Maybe there is a simple flag like that could do this but you would need to find it and i dont think its worth the effort. Another way is maybe, since its a mail service, make it write a mail to one of your emails every 5 minutes and if the mail doesnt arive restart it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston that's interesting, I might try it... problem being that I can only debug it when it has stalled and I don't know where that might happen. I was looking for a more general way (so I could test it by making any application unresponsive and testing against it), but I might look into that.

Comment: I don't think there's any generic solution, it depends on what exactly the code is doing after it fails.

Comment: @Vajura that's a way but I'd prefer not to have any side effects (like a mail being sent in this case), or actually depend on the specific service implementation. I was hoping there'd be a general way for any service. Will try querying the service status as Harry Johnston hinted above

Comment: Unfortunately a status query is very simple and it is entirely possible that it will keep working even after the service has failed.  But it is worth a try next time you have the opportunity.  You can do it easily enough from the command line, `sc query servicename`.

Comment: Yes, I was going to do exactly that for testing :-)

Comment: I dont think a generic way exists for every application. Some applications might appear to be a deadlock where they are actualy just doing what they are supposed to. And btw does the program when it freezez spike CPU usage? Then you could restart it with that

Comment: I just found out (hadn't looked before, shame on me) that it's written in .NET so I can just find out what IPC notifications it responds to by decompiling it with dotpeek or similar. I might start there, the code doesn't look all that complicated (the service is quite simple indeed)

Comment: Check out [Service Protector](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceProtector/), a commercial application that tries to solve a similar problem. Perhaps one of the [failure-detection utilities](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Plugins/) will detect the hang -- maybe the "not listening on a network port" one?

Comment: @CoreTech I'm evaluating your software now... I had developed a watchdog by sending a message to the executable and expecting a reply but it's not always working (sometimes I don't get a reply back but the service is working) and I don't have time to investigate it further now. Most of the times it hangs, it also hogs the CPU (one of the cores at least, so it gets 25% CPU spikes) so your app might detect it. If it works during the try-out perioid, we'll buy it :-)